# facebook api limit offset does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-fql

I have fql query like these.

```
SELECT name, page_id, type, pic_cover, fan_count, about FROM page where page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me()) LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
SELECT name, page_id, type, pic_cover, fan_count, about FROM page where page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me()) LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
```

Although the first query is work very well, the second one doesn't return anything. Is there any change in facebook api for offset. Is there any way to handle with this problem?

Comment: I think this is a Facebook bug. Doesn't work for me either...

Answer (score 1):

Guess it's too late. The problem is with using `IN` keyword. The second query must be

`SELECT name, page_id, type, pic_cover, fan_count, about FROM page where page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me() limit 100 offset 100)`

LIMIT and OFFSET are in inner query.

Hope this helps.